# Detect MVC authentication timeout across multiple tabs of same app

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, signalr

We're building an ASP.NET MVC 5 app that can have multiple tabs open to the same session. Is it possible to detect the authentication timeout using AJAX or SignalR without extending the timeout?

We've found these articles that talk about using the `OnActionExecuting` on a custom `ActionFilter` to detect timeout during a server call:

- http://findnerd.com/list/view/ASP-NET-MVC-How-to-check-session-timeout-and-redirect-to-login-page-/11664/
- http://mvc-ajax.blogspot.com/2016/01/aspnet-mvc-session-expire-handling.html
- https://markfreedman.com/handling-session-and-authentication-timeouts-in-asp-net-mvc/

However, none provide a way to simply read a property from the server -- without extending the timeout -- to see if the session is about to expire. Is there a way via AJAX/SignalR to poll the server from any tab and get the session timeout without extending the session?